# Extracting zip codes in excel in unstructured data

Tags: excel

[image]

I'm working with excel 2016. I have some unstructured data as in the screenshot. I would like to extract the zip code ( which should be the last 5 digit number in each cell ).

I'm new to excel . Do I need to install and use regex to extract the zip code([How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops))

or is there a more standard not vb related function/group of functions in excel that can do this?

Comment: can it be said that the zip code will always be the second to last grouping delineated by the comma?

Comment: Yes, Lets assume that

Comment: What about the hyphen inside "78154-1265"? Would that be what you are after (since you spoke about the 5 digit number)? Also, please include your own attempt at solving this issue to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the zip code is always the second to last group delineated by commas:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","{{{",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))-1))+2,5)
```

[image]

Or if one has it FILTERXML:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]")
```

[image]